# let child dom element out of bounds of the parent div with html and javascript on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

It is very hard to summarize in the title what the question is exactly 
so more info here...

I have an image-gallery consisting of a list element with images (and a span to display a text label).
The HTML layout looks like this:

```
            <div class="caracteristics_list gallery">

                <ul class="thumb">
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="video">Play</span><img src="images/gallery1.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery1.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery1.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery2.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery2.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery2.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="tagline">Lorem ipsum</span><img src="images/gallery3.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="tagline">Lorem ipsum</span><img src="images/gallery3.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery3.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery3.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery4.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery4.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                </ul>                    
            </div>
```

This gallery has a zoom effect ([taken from this guide](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/fancy-thumbnail-hover-effect-w-jquery/)  ([demo](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/examples/image-zoom/)))

The catch here is that the gallery has a fixed width, and height
and an `overflow: scroll` (it does not grow, it is contained within the bounds of that gallery div).

That means, the zoom effect is cut of by the overflow css settings.

An example of what I have now (with broken images though) [can be seen on jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/aaSKy/).

I fear the overflow constraint will make this method impossible, unless i take the element out of the gallery div, and position it exactly at the same spot, absolute or relative.

But first I want to make sure that is the only way to go.
Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't take out the image, make a copy of it and show out of the div. Destroy the object when it needs to be closed

Comment: this is in fact what i needed to do
but due to time shortage we decided to alter the div that has overflow on it and now it has enough padding, not to cover the items going behind it.

since we don't have the problem with endless height (limited items) we do not have a problem with scrolling where an item would then be half visible or be covered again at the bottom.

so your solution is in fact the right one, but we choose a dirty solution that works in our situation but not in every situation.
thanks